# Tabular data to matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to remove the shackles of some legacy code that we use to make decision trees in a retail setting.  I got to playing with hclust in R and it's beautiful and I'd like to use it.  The heavy lifting for calculating distances is done in SQL and I get an output like this:

```
main   with   dist
A      A      0.00
A      B      1.37
A      C      0.64
B      B      0
B      C      0.1
C      C      0
```

That's loaded as a data frame right now (just reading the SQL query dump), but hclust wants a matrix of distances.  E.g.,:

```
     A      B     C
--+-----------------
A |  0
B |  1.37   0
C |  0.64   0.1   0
```

My thinking is too procedural and I'm trying to do it in nested loops at the moment.  Can someone point me in the direction of something more R-idiomatic to do this?

Thank!

Comment: Something like this could work `dcast(x, main ~ with)`. Actually I don't see a problem using nested loops in this case (done this myself).

Comment: @ananda... i truncated my data in the example.  i'll go add a row.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an actual distance matrix in R, try:

```
as.dist(xtabs(dist ~ with + main, mydf), diag = TRUE)
#      A    B    C
# A 0.00          
# B 1.37 0.00     
# C 0.64 0.10 0.00
```

---

I'm presuming that the combinations of "main" and "with" are unique, otherwise `xtabs` would sum the "dist" values.

Comment: xtabs did the trick.  I left out the mydf argument and the diag (diag caused an error about an unused argument?).  But anyway, it turned my table into a matrix, and then I coerced the matrix into a distance matrix saying, "Trust my values":

    x = read.table("C:/x_metrics_export.out",sep="|",header=F);
    names(x) = c("main","with","dist");
    tt = xtabs(dist ~ with + main,data=x); #Make the table into a matrix.
    clustdist = as.dist(tt); #Say to R, "Trust me, this is a matrix of distances."
    xclust = hclust(clustdist); #Build the tree
    plot(xclust);

Comment: @Chris, `diag` is an argument to `as.dist`, so watch your brackets :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change from letters to numbers (which is straight forward using the ASCII codes) and then use the linearized indices of R matrices to access each pair in a vectorwise manner.

Minimal example:

```
N <- 3
d <- data.frame(x = c(1,2), y = c(2,3), v = c(0.1, 0.2))
m <- matrix(0, N, N)
m[(d$y-1)*N+d$x] = d$v
```

The output is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0  0.1  0.0
[2,]    0  0.0  0.2
[3,]    0  0.0  0.0
```

EDIT: To preserve arbitrary strings as row and col names, consider the following example:

```
codes <- c('A','B','C')
N <- 3
d <- data.frame(x = c('A','B'), y = c('B','C'), v = c(0.1, 0.2))
m <- matrix(0, N, N)
m[(vapply(d$y, function(x) which(codes == x), 0)-1)*N+
   vapply(d$x, function(x) which(codes == x), 0)] = d$v
rownames(m) = codes
colnames(m) = codes
```

Comment: The letters are actually product UPC codes, which I've replaced with letters in this example.  It's important to me to keep the UPCs as the labels so that the resulting dendrogram is something that I can inspect and say, "Ah, interesting!"